# How to get AngularUI sortable cloning items in connected lists

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I'm trying to get AngularUI to clone items from one list to the other. Its not working.

I think I have the options correct, but not sure. I'm sure it's something silly.. 
These are my options:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    connectWith: ".sort",
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false
};
```

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Npyyg/

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this CodePen example: http://cdpn.io/akCIe

I think it does what you are looking for.  The sortableOptions include 'stop' & 'update' functions instead of using helper:"clone" which doesn't seem to work.

```
  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    connectWith: ".apps-container",
    update: function (e, ui) {
      if (ui.item.sortable.droptarget.hasClass('first')) {
        ui.item.sortable.cancel();
      }
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
      if ($(e.target).hasClass('first') &&
          e.target != ui.item.sortable.droptarget[0]) {
        $scope.sourceScreens = originalScreens.slice();
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, its been a rough month.. Thanks for the tip :) The angularjs sortable doesn't work. I'm rewriting an full editor abstraction directive to integrate text and graphic objects ie svg. Sortable is an editable layout object